# Displaying correct filename on embedded files in a RichTextBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

I have a simple C#.Net application with a `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` control. To enable drag and drop, I have set `EnableAutoDragDrop` property to `true`.

When I drag and drop files into this `RichTextBox`, some files display the filename it had on the disk, while others show a generic name depending on the format of the file.

[image]

For example, `DOCX`, `PDF`, and `XSLX` files show a generic file name, while `TXT` and `JPG` show the correct file name.

**How can I make my `RichTextBox` control to show the correct filename for *all* types of embedded files?** I would like to see a result similar to this:

[image]

So far, I have tried subscribing to the `DragDrop` event and seeing if I can manipulate any attribute in the `DragEventArgs` and `DragEventArgs.Data` objects. I have done various tests by calling `DragEventArgs.Data.SetData()`, with no luck.

Comment: can you show your Drag and Drop code ?

Comment: @Krishna: There is no drag and drop code. Just `EnableAutoDragDrop` enabled. I will add this to the question.